# why am I getting org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration?

Tags: java, hibernate

I´ve a hibenate cfg file but when I try to use hibernate in my application I get: Grave: Ocurrió un error en la inicialización de la SessionFactory: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- parametros para la conexion a la base de datos -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <!-- Configuracion del pool interno -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">50</property>

        <!-- Dialecto de la base de datos -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <!-- Otras propiedades importantes -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>  

        <!-- Archivos de mapeo -->
        <mapping class="com.proximate.model.Usuarios"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and here is my hibernate util:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            System.err.println("Ocurrió un error en la inicialización de la SessionFactory: " + he);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void close() {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

What´s wrong with my configuration???
Thanks in advance

Comment: `<prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>` – the tag is `property`, not `prop`.

Comment: you are right so after changing it I get No CurrentSessionContext configured! when I do Query query = sessionFactory.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery